# Java return value only from within a loop

Tags: java, methods

I have a method where I need to return a specific object if found, otherwise throw an exception. So I wrote the following:

```
public CustomerDetails findCustomer( String givenID ) throws CustomerNotFoundException{
    for(CustomerDetails nextCustomer : customers){
        if(givenID == nextCustomer.getCustomerID()){
            return nextCustomer;
        }else{
            throw new CustomerNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

But it requires me to add a return statement at the bottom of the method. Is there a way to ignore this?

Comment: What do you want to happen if `customers` is empty? And do you *really* want to throw an exception if the very *first* customer is not the one you want? (That's what your current code would do... you'll never go into a second iteration of the loop.)

Comment: The compiler actually complains about the case where the `customers` collection is empty. In that case, neither the `return` nor the `throw` are executed. You should implement it the way `TheLostMind` suggested below.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, only after reading them I realized how stupid the exception was implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It asks you to provide a valid outcome from the method for the case when the loop is not executed (i.e. `customers` is empty). You have to do this:

```
for (CustomerDetails nextCustomer : customers){
    if (givenID == nextCustomer.getCustomerID()){
        return nextCustomer;
    }
}
throw new CustomerNotFoundException();
```

because otherwise you would throw the exception after the first element that doesn't meet the condition provided in the `if`.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to :

```
public CustomerDetails findCustomer( String givenID ) throws CustomerNotFoundException{
    for(CustomerDetails nextCustomer : customers){
        if(givenID == nextCustomer.getCustomerID()){
            return nextCustomer;
        }
    }
    throw new CustomerNotFoundException();
}
```

Comment: this is not the same logic as in quesiton. It will loop through every customer if given id not equals

Comment: @VishnudevK - Actually, the OPs logic was wrong.. He will throw an exception if the first element doesn't match the expected id.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the object if it is found. If it will be not found it throw an exception at end of the loop:

```
public CustomerDetails findCustomer( String givenID ) throws CustomerNotFoundException{
    for(CustomerDetails nextCustomer : customers){
        if(givenID.equals(nextCustomer.getCustomerID())){
            return nextCustomer;
       }
    }
       throw new CustomerNotFoundException();
}
```

Note. you compare `strings` with `==`. Here you have to usethe `equals` method!

Comment: this is not the same logic as in quesiton. It will loop through every customer if given id not equals

Comment: @VishnudevK but that is the logic what OP is searching for.

Answer (score 0):

An exception should be thrown if an unexpected behavior occurs. A failed search is not an exception, but a rarely common cause.

For the reason of good design, you should not throw the exception. Instead you can expand your calling method to test the result for null-iness or similiar.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `return;` at the end of your method. It won't be accessible so it won't cause issues.

You could also use a try catch around your loop. Here is a handy tutorial for that if you wish to follow this route.
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html

Answer (score 0):

If the customer could not be found in the loop, it should throw exception out of the loop. Also you should use ".equals" instead of "==", because "givenID" is an object.

```
public CustomerDetails findCustomer( String givenID ) throws CustomerNotFoundException {
    for (CustomerDetails nextCustomer : customers) {
        if (givenID.equals(nextCustomer.getCustomerID())){
            return nextCustomer;
        }
    }
    throw new CustomerNotFoundException();
}
```